# Refresh a view in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a GridView that pulls data from a SQL query on an asp.net page. When the page loads, the query will return no results until all the elements of the page are completed.

How can I use a button (or any other method) to refresh the view once I have completed the rest of the page?

Thank you!

Comment: just pass the default parameter value to your method on page load

Answer (score 0):

Rebind to the grid again once you are done with all your page load like

```
gridview1.DataSource = <some data source>;
gridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Code is not working for me. If the database is empty when I load the page, it will not show the view ever. IF the db is prepopulated, the view shows right away. I mist have made a mistake sonewhere thanks for the help.

Comment: Post your code. That will help understand the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
               gridview1.DataSource = <some data source>;
               gridview1.DataBind();  
        }
    }
```